# Maven jar not able to read the data from TestData sheets from src/test/resources folder

Tags: maven, selenium, excel-2010, testng

I have a maven test automation project developed using selenium and testng.
This is what I am doing with my framework:

1. I have main class in src/main/java and within the main class I trigger methods to dynamically create and run the testng xml.
2. The tests to be run are determined from the XMLFlag.xls and TestNG.xlsx sheets in src/test/resources.
3. I am able to successfully run the test scripts using "mvn test" command.

Now I want to run my entire project by creating a jar.
I am able to create a jar with all dependencies using "maven-assembly-plugin" but I am unable to run the scripts because the test data sheets in src/test/resources are not identified.

I am getting an error message as below:-

> Error message : .\src\test\resources\XMLFlag.xls (The system cannot
>   find the path specified)

Can you guys kindly help me out!
 [Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9eR2.png)

I have mentioned the paths to XMLFlag.xls and TestNG.xlsx in my code as below:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(".\\src\\test\\resources\\XMLFlag.xls");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(".\\src\\test\\resources\\TestNG.xlsx");
```

I would like the jar to read the required test data from these sheets and execute the scripts.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, when creating jar, only files from `src/main/resources` and `src/main/java` will appear there. I recommend you to move your resources from the `src/test/resources` to `src/main/resources`. You can also configure `maven-jar-plugin` to include the files but it requires more configuration. Having tests and tests sources in `src/main` is imho ok.

Secondly, once packed in a jar, path `src/<whatever>/resources` becomes irrelevant. You need to load the file by using a classloader; otherwise you would need to unpack your jar manually and load the files from the unpacked location.
Since files from `src/main/resources` appear in the root of the jar file, to load your files, just do

```
InputStream stream = YourClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("XMLFlag.xls");
```

Note that `YourClassName` should be substituted with your class name.
Also note that you cannot use `FileInputStream` because you're not accessing a file (just something what is packed inside a jar file).

Comment: Hi @Stepan Vavra, thank you so much for this. I had been struggling for a long time to set this up...I made the changes as u suggested and I am able to run the jar..However, i would really like to know if having the Test data files in src/main/resources is fine?

Comment: Well, it depends. :-) You can also create a `test-jar` from your tests classes (and resources) (see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/test-jar-mojo.html); however, that usually leads to problems. If you don't need to put your tests into jar, you can use `src/test/java` folder for test classes and `src/test/resources` for test resources. That would still work (for instance, if you execute the tests by maven). Anyway, having tests classes in your project jar is wrong; it should be avoided. It is ok to create additional *test-support* jar module where tests can be in `src/main`.

Comment: Hi @stepan vavra, thanks for the information..i still have a few queries related to my post..as u suggested, i am able to create a jar with all my tests and test data in it..but I think  that this is not 100% correct because the test scripts have to be run for different sets of test data..if my test data sheet is packaged within the jar, i will not be able to run the scripts for other sets of data..is there a workaround for this?

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand your current problem. Maybe, you can ask another question or extend the current one. You can also try to describe more in detail your current situation. I can give it a try though and try to answer - how about excluding the test data from the test jar?

Comment: Hi @Stepan, I have clearly explained my issue in a new question "Maven Test Automation Project".
Can you kindly help me out?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maven makes the difference between the resources of the compiliation and test src/main/resources and src/test/resources, you have resources scoped test and hand in the class scope compilation:

1. The solution is to move the 2 files in src/main/resources and make the call:

   ```
   String file = "src/main/resources/XMLFlag.xls";
   FileInputStream stream1 = new FileInputStream (file1);
   ```
2. The second solution is more propore is not to hand and create a test class in src/test/java and resources as your classes and use the same test scope ie target/test-classes